# Script to create new html documents

Tags: html, bash, shell, csv, zsh

I'm looking to make a script that will create new html documents following a basic template, but with various placeholders within it to be swapped out for items I have in a csv. I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on how to go about this.

Example of what I'd like to do.

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
     First item in csv
    </TITLE>
   </HEAD>

   <BODY>
    <p>Second item in csv</p>
   </BODY>
</HTML>

Items: John Smith, He is 42

Output = john_smith.html

<HTML>
   <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
     John Smith
    </TITLE>
   </HEAD>

   <BODY>
    <p>He is 42</p>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: There must be a million template engines out there.

Comment: could you please point me in the direction of one

Comment: I'd rather not, because there are so many of them, and I don't have much experience in this area... If you really ask me, I've had success with a very simple one, [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Comment: By the way, in your example case a heredoc is enough. But I'm not sure if it really reflect your complexity and use case.

Comment: I would seriously suggest some suitable server side programming language for this job like python or node since they are OOP languages... : /...no offence

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105531/14650

Comment: can we please vote to close this as an off-topic recommendation Q? @emmet, sorry, but good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example to create multiple html files from a csv file with bash:

file.csv:

```
John Smith, He is 42
Jane Doe, She is 25
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r name age; do
  cat << EOF > "${name// /_}.html"
    <HTML>
       <HEAD>
        <TITLE>
         $name
        </TITLE>
       </HEAD>

       <BODY>
        <p>${age# *}</p>
       </BODY>
    </HTML>
EOF
done < file.csv
```

This creates two files: John_Smith.html and Jane_Doe.html

---

See: `help while`, `help read`, [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

> `${name// /_}.html`: replace all whitespaces by `_` in output
>
> `${age# *}`: remove leading whitespace in output